# how to calculate vb1 and vo in this TTL circuit?

Tags: ttl

[image: TTL circuit]

By referring to question (i) how to calculate Vb1 and Vo? can i assume Vb1=Vbe(sat) and Vo=5v?

Comment: Do you get reasonable, self-consistent results if you do?

Comment: @DaveTweed since its a NAND gate, when the input is LOW then the output will be HIGH. So, i assume Vo is 5V since the input is 0.1v. Can you explain how it actually works? and what is Vb1?

Comment: \$v_{B1}\$ is one diode drop above the lowest of \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$ (or its own collector voltage). What does this tell you about the operating state of Q1 and what its collector voltage must be? Is this consistent with your assumption that Q0 is cut off?

Comment: @DaveTweed the operating state of Q1 is forward bias and and the collector voltage is 0v since the current from Q0 base cant go out to Q1. is it correct sir? can u explain how to get Vo and Vb1 actually?

Comment: No, Q1 is in either "cutoff", "forward active", "reverse active" or "saturated" modes. Which is it?

Comment: @DaveTweed Q1 is in forward active

Comment: Which would mean that its \$I_C = \beta \times I_B\$. Is that in fact the case?

Comment: @DaveTweed in the question, there is no  value.

Comment: @DaveTweed can you help me to solve question (i)?

Comment: But you know that \$\beta\$ must be a positive value, representing a ratio. But what else do you know about \$I_C\$ from the circuit diagram?

Comment: I AM helping you -- but I'm not going to just hand you a solution. This appears to be a homework question. Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed Ic cannot flow to Q1 because it connected to Q0 base which is the current cannot flow toward Q1 direction.

Comment: @DaveTweed so the state of Q0 transistor is off

Comment: Not so fast. We still haven't worked out what Q0's base voltage is. What does the fact that \$I_B > \frac{I_C}{\beta}\$ tell you about the actual operating mode of Q1? And what does that tell you about its collector voltage?

Comment: @DaveTweed i dont get it sir

Comment: All right. I'll write it up as an answer, but it's clear that you're not ready for this exercise. You need to go back and review some basic concepts about BJT operations.

Comment: @DaveTweed when >/  is it in saturation mode?

Comment: @DaveTweed So, when collector current is 0 then the collector voltage is also 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're told that at least one of Vx or Vy is at 0.1V.

This means that the corresponding BE junction(s) of Q1 are forward biased. Therefore, Q1 must be either in "forward active" or "saturated" mode. Which one?

From the circuit configuration, we can see that there is no source of current into Q1's collector, so it must be zero. Therefore, regardless of the actual current gain (β) of Q1 or its base current value, it must be saturated.

Now we can state that Q1's collector voltage is \$V_E + V_{CE(sat)} = 0.1V + 0.1V = 0.2V\$

Since this is also the base voltage for Q0, and it is much less than \$V_{BE(on)}\$, we can conclude that Q0 is cut off.

Therefore, Vo = 5V via Rc.

We can go back and calculate
$$V_{B1} = V_E + V_{BE(sat)}= 0.1V + 0.8V = 0.9V$$
$$I_{B1} = \frac {Vcc - V_{B1}}{R1}= \frac {5V - 0.9V}{3k\Omega} = 1.37 mA$$

Comment: Thank you so much sir! appreciate it!